Powershell: select all items after Nth item
tl;dr in Powershell using a pipeline, how do I select items N and afterward?
In Powershell, I want to delete the oldest files from a directory except for the most recent 10.
I can sort the files by LastWriteTime and then remove some of them using Select-Object
PS> Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Temp -File `
    | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime `
    | Select-Object -First 6 `
    | Remove-Item -Verbose

Running the prior snippet, it will delete 6 files at a time, until no more files remain.  But I want the most recent 10 files to never be deleted.
How can I make delete down to the 10 most recent files in a directory?

Use the -Skip operator from Select-Object.
From the example snippet, change from Select-Object -First 6 to Select-Object -Skip 6.
PS> Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Temp -File `
    | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime `
    | Select-Object -Skip 6 `
    | Remove-Item -Verbose


You need to use descending like Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime, Name -Descending

You need the -skiplast parameter.
PS> Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Temp -File `
    | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime `
    | Select-Object -Skiplast 10`
    | Remove-Item -Verbose

